# Morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^1_K$, rational functions, global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm confused about the two descriptions of morphisms $\varphi:\mathcal{C}\to\mathbb{P}^1_K$ with $\mathcal{C}$ a curve over a field $K$.

If we take $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{P}^1_K$ then such a morphism can be associated a morphism $K(u)\to K(t)$ if $K(u)$ and $K(t)$ are respectively function field of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ and $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{P}^1_K$. Such a morphism is characterized by the image of $u$ that is an element $f\in K(t)$.

One has $f=P/Q$ with $P,Q\in K[t]$ coprimes. One can also take $f=\widetilde{P}/\widetilde{Q}$ with $\widetilde{P}(X,Y)$ and $\widetilde{Q}(X,Y)$ homogeneous polynomials of same degre obtained with $t=X/Y$ and simplifying. Pay attention that $\widetilde{P}$ and $\widetilde{Q}$ are not exactly the homogeneization of $P$ and $Q$ but for example $\widetilde{Q}=Y^q\overline{Q}$ with $\overline{Q}$ is the homogeneization and $q$ is the difference of degree between $P$ and $Q$.

I think we can describe $\varphi$ as the element of $\mathbb{P}^1_K(\mathcal{C})$ defined by the two homogeneous polynomials $\widetilde{P}$ and $\widetilde{Q}$ as global sections generating the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(d)$ (following standard description of morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^n$ like in Hartshorne II.7.1(b)). For that I need that the only prime homogeneous $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K[X,Y]$ containing the ideal $(\widetilde{P},\widetilde{Q})$ is the irrelevant $(X,Y)$.

**Question**: How prove that $(X,Y)$ is the only prime homogeneous ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $(\widetilde{P},\widetilde{Q})$?

I have some ideas:

as $P$ and $Q$ are coprime one has $PR+QS=1$ so taking $t=X/Y$ and as $PR$ and $QS$ have the same degree $d$ so one has $\overline{P}\overline{R}+\overline{Q}\overline{S}=Y^d$ with $\overline{blabla}$ are the homogeneizations. Here there is a problem because a priori $\overline{P}\neq\widetilde{P}$ and the same for $Q$. Without this problem I get $Y^d\in(\widetilde{P},\widetilde{Q})$ so if $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq(\widetilde{P},\widetilde{Q})$ then $\mathfrak{p}\ni Y$.

Then I should prove that $\mathfrak{p}\ni X$ and I don't see how to get that. Maybe use that $t\in(P,Q)$ but I only get that $XY^d\in(\widetilde{P},\widetilde{Q})$ (and the same problem with $\overline{P}\neq\widetilde{P})$.